# JavaScript & HTML - Stop Background Sound after Video Screen is Exit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I want to stop the video from playing the video background sound or stop the sounds it AFTER I exit the video screen.

Full screen

[image]

The bug right now is the video background sound is still playing right after I exit the video screen. so I just want to remove the video background sound.

here is my video

```
 <video oncontextmenu="return false;" src="../inflightapp/storage/app/public/series_videos/<?php echo ''.$row5['episode_video'].''; ?>" id="<?php echo ''.$row5['id'].'';?>" width="1px" controls controlsList="nodownload"></video>
```

Javascript

```
 var video = document.getElementById(title);   
    document.onkeypress = function(e){
        if((e || window.event).keyCode === 32){
            video.paused ? video.play() : video.pause();
        }
    };
    $('video.series-video').bind('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange', function(e) {
    var state = document.fullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen;
    var event = state ? 'FullscreenOn' : 'FullscreenOff';
```

Comment: I think you can do this by triggering `video.pause()` while you exit the video screen. If your situation is different please describe it.

Comment: let's say i want to escape using `esc` how can i do that sir? or how can I pause it sir?

Comment: i just have a basic page and i have that video src.

Comment: how can i trigger it using `video.pause()` ??

Comment: @Sivaprasad I have a full screen video screen

Comment: how you are exiting from the full screen mode? you can use the pause() function while you exit the full screen right?

Comment: even the Escape key press can be triggered to call pause()

Comment: Yes sir you are right i tried it and closed the modal it work but didnt in the video becaue it is in full screen . the alert cannot be detect when the video is in full screen

Comment: i have this code 
 '$(document).keyup(function(e) {
     if (e.key === "Escape") { // escape key maps to keycode `27`
         alert('Video');
    }
});'

Comment: but it is not working when the video is in full screen

Comment: can you show me how you did that? did you checked the scope of the variable video.

Comment: im just pressing the escape key and the alert is popping up but i cannot pop up in the video with full screen

Comment: try this `document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;
  if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
   video.pause();
  }
 };`

Comment: @Sivaprasad check out my image in my question above i added an image nothing still is popping on alert :( i change the video.pause to alert('test pause'); still nothing is showing

Comment: How has the video been set to fullscreen? If it were by using the Element.requestFullscreen method, then the current answer is correct, if it was by other means (e.g by clicking on the fullscreen button of the default controls), then it's an other story...

Comment: @Kaiido sir!! you are right it by clicking a button by default control

Comment: Then the fullscreen API is of no use, and I have to admit I don't know how to hook on any event in this case, I'll dig a bit, maybe mediaQueries could help

Comment: thats okay :) sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This answer seems actually a bit wrong...

Chrome does fire a `webkitfullscreenchange` event, so @Sivaprasad answer should work.
Remember though that all this is not specified, so it may very well change in the future.

---

Previous answer, until OP reverts their accept-mark.

---

Since you are not using the DOM [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API), but the browser's UI controls, you can not rely on this API to behave correctly.
Current Firefox seems to use their own deprecated `mozRequestFullScreen` API even in their UI, so here, @Sivaprasad's answer would work, but it may very well change at any time and at least current Chrome does not use this API.

An other nice solution would have been to use a [MediaQuery](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList) targeting the fullscreen state of the document, but there is no built-in media-query providing this info. However we can build one as such `@media (device-width: 100vw) and (device-height: 100vh)`, which should work pretty well.

So that's fine, let's build a MediaQueryList using [`matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) method, and listen for its change event.

That should have worked... but for whatever reasons, neither Chrome nor Firefox do trigger this change event, even though they both honor the query when set to CSS.

So this leads me to set up this horrible hack, where I will listen to the [*transitionend*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) event of a dummy element, which will trigger when the above media query will get matched through CSS.
Yes, that's an hack.

```js
// this should have worked...
const query = matchMedia('@media (device-width: 100vw) and (device-height: 100vh)');
query.onchange = e => {
  if (query.matches) console.log('entered FS');
  else console.log('exit FS')
}
//... but it doesn't

// so here is the hack...
let fs_elem = null;
myFSHack.addEventListener('transitionend', e => {
  const prev = fs_elem;
  fs_elem = document.querySelector(':fullscreen');
  if (!fs_elem && prev === myvid) {
    myvid.pause();
    console.log('exit fullscreen')
  }
})
```

```css
#myFSHack {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .1s;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: none
}

@media (device-width: 100vw) and (device-height: 100vh) {
  #myFSHack {/* trigger the transition */
    max-height: 1px;
  }
}
:root,body{margin:0;}
video {max-width: 100vw;}
```

```html
<span id="myFSHack"></span>
<h5>You may have to 'right-click'=>'fullscreen' if the standard icon doens't appear.</h5>
<video id="myvid" controls loop src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/a/a4/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm.480p.webm"></video>
```

[And as a fiddle for Chrome which does block the Fullscreen button in StackSNippet's iframes.](https://jsfiddle.net/85zsgpu2/)

Comment: sir, why is it not working on google chrome? it is working perfectly on mozilla firefox why is it not working in google chrome sir :(

Comment: @SummerWinter and actually after further testing, I found out that Chrome does fire the non-standard `webkitfullscreenchange` event, even from the UI. So @Sivaprasad's answer should work and get the Accept mark.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
            document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', exitHandler);
            document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', exitHandler);
            document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', exitHandler);
            document.addEventListener('MSFullscreenChange', exitHandler);

            function exitHandler() {
                if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.webkitIsFullScreen && !document.mozFullScreen && !document.msFullscreenElement) {
                    video.pause();
                }
            }
```

Comment: can you add a snippet sir if it worked? then ill marked i as an answer thanks

Comment: Full screen video is not supported in the code snippet, so i can't check it in snippet. It's working fine for me by simply pressing the Escape key or the exit full screen button even for the video played with default controls. This won't work for IE.

Comment: Actually I was wrong, Chrome still does emit the non-standard webkitfullscreenchnage event. (But **not** the standard one, weirdly enough...). This answer is the correct one for today, but there should probably be a note that this is very unstandardized behavior.