# HTML - Exiting Full Screen Video and Paused not working on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a video and clicking it in full screen is working well but when I pressed the escape or when I cancel the full screen, the video is still playing and not pausing the audio. I tried my code in Mozilla Firefox and it is working but when I tried it on Google Chrome it is not working. help please thanks.

Here is my code

```js
// this should have worked...
const query = matchMedia('@media (device-width: 100vw) and (device-height: 100vh)');
query.onchange = e => {
  if (query.matches) console.log('entered FS');
  else console.log('exit FS');
}
//... but it doesn't

// so here is the hack...
let fs_elem = null;
myFSHack.addEventListener('transitionend', e => {
  const prev = fs_elem;
  fs_elem = document.querySelector(':fullscreen');
  if (!fs_elem && prev === myvid) {
    myvid.pause();
    console.log('exit fullscreen')
  }
});
```

```css
#myFSHack {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .1s;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: none
}

@media (device-width: 100vw) and (device-height: 100vh) {
  #myFSHack {/* trigger the transition */
    max-height: 1px;
  }
}
:root,body{margin:0;}
video {max-width: 100vw;}
```

```html
<span id="myFSHack"></span><!-- This Line of Code this is the one which helps me to pause the full screen video when escaped or cancel --> 
<h5>Click the View Full Screen</h5>
<video id="myvid" controls loop src="video/flashtrailer.mp4"></video>
```

Comment: [I replied to your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54104600/javascript-html-stop-background-sound-after-video-screen-is-exit#comment95112143_54106711), please don't use the code I did provide, [@Sivaprasad's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54105590/3702797) will work and this is the one you should use.

Comment: @Kaiido , i ve been confused lately, will i just copy it or i will add something on the code?

Comment: @Kaiido can you help me more sir :( ? please

Comment: No just running it will set up an event handler that should fire whenever you'll exit the fullscreen mode, and in this handler your video will get paused.